# pcolormesh rescale axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a messy bit of code to create a heat map from simulation data pasted below. In the code, `heatdataraw` is an m x n array containing the simulation data, where `n` is the number of simulations and `m` is the number of timesteps in a single simulation.

```
elsinrow = len(heatdataraw[0])
ts = range (elsinrow)
times = []

for x in range (len(heatdataraw)) :
    times.append(ts)

times = np.array(times)
#times = times * timescale
times = times.flatten()
heatdata = heatdataraw.flatten()

binsize = 100
xbins = np.arange(0,elsinrow,binsize)
ybins = np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,elsinrow/binsize)
    
heatdatabinned = stats.binned_statistic_2d(times,heatdata,heatdata,'count',bins=[xbins,ybins])

heatdatabinned = np.array(heatdatabinned.statistic)
heatdatabinned = heatdatabinned.T
    
xbins = xbins + (xbins[1]-xbins[0])/2
ybins = ybins + (ybins[1]-ybins[0])/2

xbins = xbins[:-1]
ybins = ybins[:-1]

heatmap, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.pcolormesh(xbins,ybins,heatdatabinned,cmap='inferno',vmin=0,vmax=binsize*1)
ax.set(xlabel='timestep', ylabel='$\\langle$ state $\\rangle$')

cbar = heatmap.colorbar(im)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('counts')

heatmap.savefig('heatmap.png')
```

At the moment, the x axis of this plot will display some integers 0 to N, where N is the number of timesteps. This is unfortunate, because I'd like to use the actual time instead on the x axis. So, I'd like to either (preferably) rescale the x-axis, or (possibly) rescale the x data. I have accomplished neither. My most intuitive attempt so far has simply been to rescale the x data with the timestep (commented line in code).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that is actually *not* a proper answer to the question, but that solved my issue in this particular case.

If we change pcolormesh for imshow, then we can use `extent`, like so:

```
im = ax.imshow(heatdatabinned,cmap='inferno',vmin=0,vmax=binsize*1,extent=[xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax],interpolation='nearest',origin='lower',aspect='auto')
```

where `im = ax.imshow(...)` substitutes `im = ax.pcolormesh(...)`.

Back to thesis writing!